# Having trouble loading library dependency gatling-grpc into my scala project

Tags: grpc, gatling

I am a newbie to the whole load testing world and trying to get gatling-grpc working within a scala script to be used within Taurus.

I am using IntelliJ as the IDE and SBT.  I keep getting the following error when compiling my module with SBT:

[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.github.phisgr:gatling-grpc_2.13:0.9.0

Here is my current build.sbt:

```
PB.targets in Test := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scalapb"
)

name := "cfd-gatling"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

scalacOptions := Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-target:jvm-1.8", "-deprecation",
  "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.4.0" % "test,it",
  "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "3.4.0" % "test,it",
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion,
  "com.github.phisgr" %% "gatling-grpc" % "0.9.0" % "test,it")

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to download by changing the scalaVersion to match the scalaVersion used in gatling-grpc github repo.

The change was this:

instead of:

scalaVersion: "2.13.3"

I used:

scalaVersion: "2.12.10"

I restarted the IDE and recompiled the project via SBT and the package was there!

Comment: Additional context: The next version of Gatling [will be in Scala 2.13](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3566).